# How to get Corresponding Column Value from a table based on Maximum values among columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table having following information.
[image]

- WageType 1 : Basic Pay
- WageType 46: Personal Pay

I want Basic Pay Max among Months columns i-e 37410 (Jan column) based on this max value i want corresponding Personal Pay Value which is 0.
I want SQL query for thr following result

[image]

use following create and Insert for above table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Salary](
[PNO] [bigint] NULL,
[WageType] [int] NULL,
[Jul] [bigint] NULL,
[Aug] [bigint] NULL,
[Sep] [bigint] NULL,
[Oct] [bigint] NULL,
[Nov] [bigint] NULL,
[Dec] [bigint] NULL,
[Jan] [bigint] NULL,
[Feb] [bigint] NULL,
[Mar] [bigint] NULL,
[Apr] [bigint] NULL,
[May] [bigint] NULL,
[Jun] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and INSERT

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Salary]
           ([PNO] ,[WageType] ,[Jul],[Aug] ,[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec],[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun])
     VALUES (123, 1,33670,33670,36240,36240,37410,37410,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    
           INSERT INTO [dbo].[Salary]
           ([PNO] ,[WageType] ,[Jul],[Aug] ,[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec],[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun])
     VALUES (123, 46,730,730,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Unpivot your data, and then get the row with the maximum value.

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very poor design for example I cant see how you're gonna store wage for more than one year. Having said that, you can normalize the data using `CROSS APPLY` then perform some aggregation:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT pno, mon, MAX(wage1) AS wage1, MAX(wage46) AS wage46
    FROM t
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
        (1,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Jan END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Jan END),
        (2,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Feb END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Feb END),
        (3,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Mar END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Mar END),
        (4,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Apr END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Apr END),
        (5,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN May END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN May END),
        (6,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Jun END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Jun END),
        (7,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Jul END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Jul END),
        (8,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Aug END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Aug END),
        (9,  CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Sep END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Sep END),
        (10, CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Oct END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Oct END),
        (11, CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Nov END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Nov END),
        (12, CASE WHEN wagetype = 1 THEN Dec END, CASE WHEN wagetype = 46 THEN Dec END)
    ) AS ca(mon, wage1, wage46)
    WHERE wagetype IN (1, 46)
    GROUP BY pno, mon
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pno ORDER BY wage1 DESC, mon ASC) AS rn
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
```